# Can't move text button

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a menu with a header background image. Now I created a text button (the green Aphryv thing) but I can't move it. I tried: margin, text-align.
You can see were the box is now and were I want it.
[image]

My code :

```css
.full-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
    
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
    
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}
    
.nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    line-height: 55px;
}
    
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}
    
.button {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #8edd63;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-header">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
         <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Aphryv</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the button you want to move?

Comment: @AustinCollins At the bottom the .button

Comment: I guess it is two lines before CSS

Comment: `text-align: center;` won't work — that has to be applied to the parent div (`.full-header`).

Comment: Have you tried to put .button the first(change the order) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the code:

```
display: inline-block;
```

You need to remove it, give the text a width, and then use margins to position it.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nc5jfd2c/

Comment: Is there a need to add position relative to the button class?

Comment: When positioning, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below changes to your `.button` class (see [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/9w1jvhms/)):

Use the following to center horizontally the button:

```
display: block; 
margin: auto;
width: 100px;
```

Add the following to center vertically the button:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Your style will become:

```
.button {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #8edd63;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your div text in a div which is positioned relative and make your div text position absolute with respect to the wrapper relative div, this how the HTML will look-

```
 <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="button">Aphryv</div>
    </div>
```

and change your button class as below

```
.button {
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 30px;
        background: #8edd63;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        margin-left:-50px;
        margin-top:60px;
    }
```

This will move the text div wrt to the relative div

Answer (score -1):

I fix it with the code from @AustinCollins

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #8edd63;
    border: 8px solid #C1E8AA;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 256px auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: So you just reposted my answer?

Comment: @AustinCollins When i did this i didn't know there was a "Accept Answer" button :#.

Comment: @Aphryv Maybe you should accept my answer if thats what solved your problem, then others could see that it worked for you.